# Wp Ecommerce Email format

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I installed wp ecommerce. I enabled "test gateway" for now. I receive the email but Email is not formatted. How to format the emails.  I tried to format the email 
// Transaction details

```
    $message = '<html><head><style type="text/css"> body {font:12px arial;} table{font:12px arial; width:60%;border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse:collapse;} td{border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse:collapse;padding:5px;}</style><body><table >';

    $message = '<tr><td><strong>' . __( 'Transaction Details', 'wpsc' ) . "</strong></tr></td>";
    $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Sale Log ID', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %purchase_id%' . "</td></tr>";

    if ( ! empty( $args['transaction_id'] ) )
        $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Transaction ID', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %transaction_id%' . "</td></tr>";

    // Discount
    if ( ! empty( $args['coupon_code'] ) ) {
        $message .='<tr><td>'. __( 'Coupon Code', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %coupon_code%' . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= '<tr><td>'.__( 'Discount Value', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %discount%' . "</td></tr>";
    }

    // Subtotal, tax, shipping, total
    $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Subtotal' ,'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %subtotal%' . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Tax', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %tax%' . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Shipping', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %shipping%' . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Total', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %total%' . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Payment Method', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %payment_method%' . "</td></tr>";

    if ( ! get_option( 'do_not_use_shipping' ) ) {
        $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Shipping Method', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %shipping_method%' . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= '<tr><td>'. __( 'Shipping Option', 'wpsc' ) ."</td><td>". ': %shipping_option%' . "</td></tr>";
    }

    $message .= "</table></body></html>";
```

I couldn't format the items, billing and shipping details. Can u pls guide me

Comment: what is the content-type in header ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text-html; charset=utf-8\"> I edited the above code in WP-Ecommerce wpsc-includes/purchase-log-notification.class